# Reading UTM_ parameters from Google AdWords and Bing Ads

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-ads-api

I'm trying to read the `utm_source` and `utm_medium` parameters being sent by Google AdWords and Bing Ads (yes, Bing Ads now sends these parameters -- it's a new feature, but you have to enable it first) but I don't know how to do so. The source of my difficulty lies in the fact that when a user clicks the ad, the user is sent to the landing page, which doesn't not have the parameters in the URL.

Here's what I'm expecting:

`http://www.mywebsites.com/lp?utm_source=Google&utc_medium=CPC`

Here's what I'm seeing:

`http://www.mywebsites.com/lp`

I know the `UTM` parameters are being sent because Google Analytics is picking them up. So how can I do this in .Net?

Comment: Where are you looking?

Comment: The query string as there is no form post.

Comment: Are you saying that you're not seeing any query string at all? Are there any intermediate redirects? can you show us your code where you're reading the query string?

Comment: Correct, there are no querystring parameters, except for the `gclid` parameter. No form parameters being passed at all. I'm I the first person who's ever tried to use the UTM parameters? Ha!

Comment: What `gclid` parameter is that? as it's not in either URL?